# Unclear on melonJS use of callback

Tags: javascript, callback, bind, melonjs

Following [this melonJS tutorial](http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial/), I'm stumped by a couple ways this callback is used (Scroll down to **Part 2: Loading our level**, you will see complete code)

```
// Set a callback to run when loading is complete.
me.loader.onload = this.loaded.bind(this);
```

I read [this tutorial on callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), so I understand what they're used for... But I don't understand. It says `this.loaded.bind(this)`

1) What is the difference between this first and second `this` statements

2) what does doing `bind` and passing in `(this)` do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind(this)` sets the context of the function

If you only set it to `this.loaded`, the context is not preserved

This might make a little more sense

```
var cntx = this;
me.loader.onload = function() {
  cntx.loaded();
}
```

However, in this example, no arguments are passed to the `loaded` function. By using the `bind` one-liner, you preserve context, and you don't have to worry about any arguments being dropped along the way.

Read about [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) here

Comment: What is `this` in this case, and what do you mean by context?

Comment: @Growler, please read about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)